Choroplethr Zip Code Map Not Displaying When reference_map=FALSE
I am creating a choropleth map of zip codes in southeast Michigan using choroplethrzip package and adding county line overlays using the geom_polygon function. My current code is below:
zip_choropleth(df,
zip_zoom = plot_zips,
reference_map=TRUE) +   
geom_polygon(data = countyref,
aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
alpha = 0,
color = "black",
linewidth = 0.2) +   
geom_text(data = mi_county_midpoints,
aes(x = long, y = lat, label = county),
size = 2,
color = "black",
fontface = "bold") 

The code runs just as I want it when reference_map is set to TRUE, but if I change it to FALSE or remove the argument altogether, I get the following error:
Error in `geom_text()`: Problem while computing aesthetics. Error occurred in the 3rd layer. Caused by error: object 'group' not found

If I remove the geom_text function, the error goes away but the map looks like this:
enter image description here
Then if I remove the geom_polygon function so that I'm left with just the zip_choropleth section, it works fine again. How can I plot this map with the county borders and labels without the reference map in the background? Thanks in advance!
UPDATE - dataset looks like this:



region
value




48001
1


48002
0


48003
10


48005
7


48006
3


48009
22


48014
5


48015
12


48017
32



The map displays as intended when using reference_map=TRUE


Please provide a reproducible example. This link gives guidance, but is a bit verbose. At the minimum, your code does not provide any data, so I can't just run it. I'd also like to know what version of R and the various packages you have installed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Apologies, I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow. And thank you for making the package, it's been awesome for me :) I updated my question to include a sample of the dataset (it has many more rows than shown, but all in the same structure). I am using R version 4.3.2 and using the choroplethr, choroplethrZip, choroplethrMaps, and ggplot2 packages to create the map. I also added a picture of how the map looks when reference_map=TRUE. That is the desired output, I just want the same thing without the reference map.

Update based on OP's revision, original answer at end
Based on your example df of zipcodes and values, this approach:

subsets the zipcode data from tigris to create mi_zip_sf;
subsets the county data that overlaps with the spatial geometries from mi_zip_sf

Given your example data are not complete, the features returned in this example are also not complete so keep that in mind. Further, using st_join() or similar methods will likely return a greater number of counties than you may be interested in. If you do have a list of your counties of interest, you do not have to use the st_join() method to subset your counties. Instead, you can employ the same method used to subset the zipcodes.
library(zipcodeR)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Your example zipcode data
zips <- read.table(text = "region   value
48001   1
48002   0
48003   10
48005   7
48006   3
48009   22
48014   5
48015   12
48017   32", header = TRUE)

# # Find zipcodes for Michigan (skip if you already know)
mi_zip <- search_state("MI")

# Load zip boundary sf using first two digits of zipcodes from mi_zip,
# use left_join() to 'filter' zipcodes to only those values in zips$region
mi_zip_sf <- zctas(cb = TRUE, 
                   year = 2020, # Most recent available data
                   starts_with = c("48", "49"),
                   class = "sf") %>%
  mutate(ZCTA5CE20 = as.integer(ZCTA5CE20)) %>%
  left_join(zips, ., by = join_by(region == ZCTA5CE20)) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Load county data and return only those counties that overlap with mi_zip_sf
countyref <- counties("Michigan", cb = TRUE) %>%
  st_join(., mi_zip_sf) %>%
  filter(!is.na(region))

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = mi_zip_sf,
          aes(fill = value),
          linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_sf(data = countyref,
          fill = NA,
          color = "black",
          linewidth = 0.2) +
  geom_sf_text(data = countyref,
               aes(label = NAME),
               size = 3,
               fun.geometry = st_centroid,
               colour = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))



Original answer
This is a generalised repex based on your description. I am not familiar with the zip_choropleth() function, but the approach outlined below works. When plotting geographical point, line, or polygon data, I strongly recommend using geom_sf(). Using other geoms can lead to issues. Plus, ggplot2 handles sf objects really well.
As you have not supplied a list of the counties and zip codes you are interested in, I have used  coord_sf() to zoom in on your area of interest. If you subset your data first, ggplot2 will automatically zoom to the extent of your data. Further, without any information regarding your group variable or how you want to fill your zipcode features, I have assigned them a single colour. If you update your question with more information about your data and how you want your plot to look, I will update this solution accordingly.
By default, the data in this repex both have NAD83:EPSG4269 as their CRS. If your data have different CRS, it will make your task easier if you st_transform() one of them so they are the same.
library(zipcodeR)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# # Find zipcodes for Michigan (skip if you already know)
mi_zip <- search_state("MI")

# Load zip boundary sf using first two digits of zipcodes from mi_zip
mi_zip_sf <- zctas(cb = TRUE, 
                   year = 2020, # Most recent available data
                   starts_with = c("48", "49"),
                   class = "sf")

# Load county data
countyref <- counties("Michigan", cb = TRUE)

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = mi_zip_sf,
          fill = "lightblue",
          colour = "grey50",
          linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_sf(data = countyref,
          fill = NA,
          color = "black",
          linewidth = 0.2) +
  geom_sf_text(data = countyref,
               aes(label = NAME),
               size = 3,
               fun.geometry = st_centroid,
               colour = "black") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-85, -82.75),
           ylim = c(41.6, 43))


